# How to use the new ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Edit to make it more clear

Like the title tells how to use the awesome [ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers#travel_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html#method-i-travel_to) method inside my controller. Like in tests, I want to achieve something like this:

```
SomethingConroller < ApplicationController
  def index
    travel_to some_date do
      # some stuff that it depends on the current_date 
    end
  end
end
```

Tried include the module:

```
include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
```

but I got:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Testing
```

Hoping that the date traveled to will be applied to the `view`, `view_helpers`, `controller_action`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you must, then add `require 'active_support/testing/time_helpers'` at the top of the file.

Although I've no idea what you're doing with that code. Try this instead:

```
SomethingConroller < ApplicationController
  def index
    @instance = SomeModel.find_by_date(12.days.ago)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't know it: you still have to call `include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers` after the `require 'active_support/testing/time_helpers'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're messing up your concepts here. You should use time travel to put tests in a certain time so that you can test a scenario at that new time. For example, lets say users have to renew their subscription after one year.

1. create the user(now).
2. travel to the time a year from now
3. Make sure that when the user logs in **at travelled to time** they are duly notified.

To manipulate date for queries, use 12.days.ago, 12.days.from_now, this can be used with seconds,days, minutes, years

Comment: No worries, I'd rather err on the side of more information than less information.